# HowTo Nest ViewPager2 within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I am trying to put a ViewPager2 with 2 tabs(2 fragments) within my main fragment.

My fragment class extends Fragment and I need it to contain a ViewPager2 with fragments implemented inside.
I couldn't find guides explaining this clearly on the web as all of them are being implemented within classes extending FragmentActivity and not Fragment.

For example: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2#fragment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ViewPager2 is an improved version of the ViewPager library that offers enhanced functionality and addresses common difficulties with using ViewPager.
Such implementations for nesting a ViewPager2 within a fragment are missing on the web as Android Developer guide shows an implementation within activity.

1) Your main fragment layout must have a ViewPager2 added to its XML file as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- Tabs widget can be removed if you don't need tabs on top of pager-->
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/myPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
```

2) The next step is to prepare our FragmentStateAdapter to set it as the ViewPager2 adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[] {//Initialize fragments views
//Fragment views are initialized like any other fragment (Extending Fragment)
                new FirstPagerFrag(),//First fragment to be displayed within the pager tab number 1
                new SecondPagerFrag(),
        };
        public final String[] mFragmentNames = new String[] {//Tabs names array
                "First Tab",
                "SecondTab"
        };

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa){//Pager constructor receives Activity instance
            super(fa);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFragments.length;//Number of fragments displayed
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return mFragments[position];
    }
}
```

3) Attaching the adapter to ViewPager2
This part is implemented within our fragment that contains the ViewPager2:

```
private ViewPager2 mViewPager;
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.queueContainer);//Get ViewPager2 view
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity()));//Attach the adapter with our ViewPagerAdapter passing the host activity

    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager,
            new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    tab.setText(((ViewPagerAdapter)(mViewPager.getAdapter())).mFragmentNames[position]);//Sets tabs names as mentioned in ViewPagerAdapter fragmentNames array, this can be implemented in many different ways.
                }
            }
    ).attach();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent fragment xml. add viewpager2.
create its adapter extending FragmentStateAdapter.
implements the methods.
in the createfragment method do this.

map is added to save the same instance of the fragment you created at the beginning it will always create a new fragment.
Use a map so get the same instance of the fragment every time.

```
private final Map<Integer, Fragment> fragmentMap;
```

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

```
    Fragment cachedFragment = fragmentMap.get(position);
    if (cachedFragment != null) {
        return cachedFragment;
    }
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            cachedFragment = new childfragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            cachedFragment = new childfragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            cachedFragment = new childfragment3();
            break;
        default:
            cachedFragment = null;
    }

    fragmentMap.put(position, cachedFragment);
    return cachedFragment;
}
```